# Email form showing ,PHP Content instead of executing and sending email

Tags: php, html-email

I'm trying to get a 'contact us email form' to work on my website but when I press the 'send' button, it doesnt send the email and it shows the entire contents of the .php file thats supposed to make it send? Can anybody help me please? my html page i called 'Contact_Us.html' and the PHP file is called 'contact.php".

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
        Your name<br>
        <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
        Your e-mail<br>
        <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
        Message<br>
        <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
```

and here is the .PHP

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'user@domain.com';
$subject = 'Message from a visitor on The New Moston Club Wesbite '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you, we have received your message. We will contact you shortly!');
        window.location = 'Contact_Us.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to thenewmostonclub@outlook.com sorry for any inconvenience');
        window.location = 'Contact_Us.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems like PHP is not configured properly.

Comment: Agree with @ShankarDamodaran, it looks like your `.php` is not processed by any PHP interpreter, so it is treated like an static file (`.html` or plain text file), and passed *as is* to the browser.

Comment: I see! The only problem is that I'm new to PHP, I've never really looked into it I only wanted to get an email form working and now im overfaced with it!

Answer (score 0):

does it show in your browsers URL bar c:/user/.../yourscript.php if yes then try localhost/yourscript.php